# How can I create a List of 100 points and SetPixel them random to a new black image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

At the top of the form:

```
private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
private Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);
```

In constructor:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
                {
                    points.Add(new Point(x, y));
                }
            }
```

This is what I got so far. This loops makes the List with 10000 points and I want only 100. And not sure how to make the rest.

The points can be in any color on the black image.

Comment: Well, if 100 x 100 = 10,000 then what size should the loops be for 100?  Also `Points` do not have a color

Comment: You need to use a [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) object to set values for x and y. the loop should go to 100 and then you can use random again to create random color(s). make sure to use only one instance of the Random object.. You code creates a solid block of pixels. Finally you use bitmap.SetPixel(x,y,color)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop only `10 * 10` times to get 100 points as bellow:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(x, y));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what else you need to do?

Comment: this is hardly what he means when he wrote 'random' as it is a block.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through `x` and `y` will only generate points in that range of values. If you want random points, you will need to use a `Random` object:

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    points.Add(
        new Point(
            r.Next(0, newBmp.Width), 
            r.Next(0, newBmp.Height)));
}
```

Then to draw them onto the bitmap, you can do the following:

```
foreach (var pt in points)
{
    Color c = Color.FromArgb(
        r.Next(0, 256), 
        r.Next(0, 256), 
        r.Next(0, 256));

    newBmp.SetPixel(pt.X, pt.Y, c);
}
```